# What is this time format?

Tags: php, datetime, time, timestamp

I am being returned this time format from an API:

```
1287498792000
```

Can anyone advise what format that is and how I would parse it in PHP?

Comment: We need more information than that. Where has this value come from?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This format is the Number of milliseconds since 1970-01-01.

Your date represents 2010-10-19 @ 14h33 if i'm not mistaken.

Just divide it by 1000 and use the standard php functions for unix timestamps like [`date`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) to display it or [`getdate`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getdate.php) to extract the different parts.

Comment: Thanks! It was the *1000 that threw me.

Answer (score 1):

It's a **Unix timestamp represented in milliseconds** — equivalent to the return value from [`time()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php) multiplied by 1,000 (timestamp in PHP are in seconds, not milliseconds).

You can use it directly<sup>1</sup> in PHP, e.g. for the [`date()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function:

```
print date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A', 1287498792000 / 1000);
// Outputs: Tuesday 19th of October 2010 02:33:12 PM
```

**EDIT**
<sup>1</sup> Yes, it seems to be in milliseconds. Divide by 1,000 in order to get a timestamp that PHP understands.

Comment: Dont think so the current unixtimestamp is 1287652876, that way too far ahead in the future if thats the case?

Comment: But in a ajavascript representation, which shows the standard timestamp multiplied by 1000. To get a normak timestamp, you'd have to divide it by 1000

Comment: Alex you should put that as an answer! divide the value with 1000 and you get the unix timestamp :)

Answer (score 0):

It's a UNIX timestamp - it represents the count of seconds since January 1st, 1970.
You can use PHP's `date()` function to convert it to a human readable format.